# Can someone explain how router works exactly in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning nodejs with express and I'm confused as to how routers work.

Why is it like this:

```
router.post('/signup', authController.signup);
router.get('/logout', authController.logout);
router.post('/login', authController.login);
```

and not like this:

```
router.post('/signup', authController.signup());
router.get('/logout', authController.logout());
router.post('/login', authController.login());
```

as in why we are not calling/invoking the functions? Will express invoke those functions on matching the url?

Comment: Those are *middleware* functions. It's more of an **express** question than NodeJS itself (although you should read about callbacks as well I suppose). You should read about middlewares in [their official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Answer (score 1):

## We use

```
router.post('/signup', authController.signup);
```

> Because in our AuthController we have defined signup methode something like

```
export function signup = (request, response, next) { // business logic }
```

- request: object has request details like URL, params, host and server request details
- response : we use response to acknowledge client and return JSON or HTML normally we use **response.send()**

## Why we don't use

```
router.post('/signup', authController.signup());
```

> Because if we use like this then our signup function we don't get request object or response so we can't return to the client with any data.
>   You can use something like (**but this is just wrapper of function so batter to use the first one**)

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => authController.signup(req, res, next));
```

[Read the official document here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)